# How do I validate Radio Buttons for the Unbounce Platform using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbounce

I'm trying to setup a contact form for a Landing Page where leads have to click on "Yes" to having read the terms of service. It would be much easier to simply have an "I accept" checkbox as opposed to "Yes" and "No" Radio Buttons but unfortunately thats what has been asked of me. I'm using Unbounce as a platform. Could someone please help me write out the code? Thanks :)

```
  lp.jQuery(function($) {

      // Config
    var ruleID = 'I have read the TOS';
    var field = 'terms_of_service';
    var message = 'Please confirm you have read the Terms of Service by clicking YES';

    var rules = module.lp.form.data.validationRules[field];

...
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with unbounce, but can't you simply `if(radioBtnVal === "Desired value"){}`? I think you may need to expand your question.

Comment: Hi there! My apologies, this is all very new to me so I may have been unclear. I need who ever lands on the page to click "YES" to having read the TOS or else they will be unable to submit the registration form! If they click "NO" I need the error message to pop-up (var message = ...) so that they know they have to click "YES" to proceed. Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is code to check if radio button or checkbox is checked. Remember you must add `checked` HTML attribute to "No" so it is checked by default.

```js
function check() {
  if ($("#yesb").prop("checked")) {
    console.log("Accepted!");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Not accepted. :-(");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input name=accepted type=radio id=yesb>Yes</label>
<label><input name=accepted type=radio id=nob checked>No</label>

<button onclick=check()>Check</button>
```